# Update product quantity in php session array if item is already there

Tags: php, session, cart

I have implemented simple shopping cart using php.I can add product in cart and it adds to array.i Get my product id on url,when i click add to cart button based on thar url id i fetch product data from database and add to session array,but my problem is when i add same product i get new entry in session and the instead of updating quantity of that product.
So what code i write to update the cart quantity if produt_id already there.?

This is print_r array value using `$_SESSION['cart']`.

```
[cart] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [product-id] => 1
                [item] => mango
                [unitprice] => 20
                [quantity] => 1
            )
         [1] => Array
            (
                [product-id] =>2
                [item] => chickoo
                [unitprice] => 20
                [quantity] => 1
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to make sure the `product_id` isn't already in your session array.  Try the following

```
$found = false;
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product)
{
    if($_REQUEST['product_id'] == $product['product_id']) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($found)
{
    $_SESSION['cart'][$_REQUEST['product_id']]['quantity'] += 1;
} else {
    // go get new product and add to $_SESSION['cart']
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks,It works....great.I tried it for 2 days but could not.How do you write nice logic?Please give me some tips to improve such  logic also i have one question,instead of this found variable,cant we write it inside for each loop if condition?why we use $found varible?

Comment: You could write it inside the for loop if you want. I generally try to keep it separate in case other logic comes up where I have to figure multiple things out about the data before I start the process in changing/manipulating it.